# Trim DataTables column values

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to show only first 100 characters of my DataTables column's cells. Something like that:

```
var columns = [

   {
      //mDataProp: 'Description'
      mDataProp: function() {
          return Description.subString(0, 100);
      },
      sTitle: 'Description'             
   },
   //
   // other columns 
   //
];
```

However I don't know how to assign a value returning from a function, to mDataProp. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using jquery datatable ?

Comment: Forgot to declare, yes it is a jquery datatables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jquery datatable you can customize cell value rendering by specifying [`fnRender`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) method like this

```
var columns = [

   {
      mDataProp: 'Description',
      fnRender: function(value) {
          return value.subString(0, 100);
      },
      sTitle: 'Description'             
   },
   //
   // other columns 
   //
];
```

`fnRender` is depreciated, if you are using older version of jQuery Datatable that will work fine. In newer version of jQuery DataTable just replace `fnRender` with `mRender`

Comment: You'll still need to tell the Datatable what data to use though so remeber to put `mDataProp: 'Description'` back into the column object.